# JS: удалить атрибуты в конкретном <></>

Tags: javascript, dom

Изображение содержит атрибут class, который подставляется CMS.

```
<img alt="" class="fill-content replaced-content" src="/image.jpg">
```

Подскажите способ удаления атрибута `class="fill-content replaced-content"`
чтобы тег выглядел вот так: `<img alt="" src="/image.jpg">`

Мой первый способ:

```
var imgRemoveClass = document.querySelectorAll("img");
    if (imgRemoveClass.hasAttribute("class")) {
        imgRemoveClass.removeAttribute("class");
    }
```

выдает ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: imgRemoveClass.hasAttribute is not a function
```

Мой второй способ:

```
var imgRemoveClass = document.querySelector("img");
    if (imgRemoveClass.hasAttribute("class")) {
        imgRemoveClass.removeAttribute("class");
    }
```

в консоли срабатывет, но при загрузке со страницы:

```
Uncaught TypeError: imgRemoveClass.hasAttribute is not a function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

в первом случае `imgRemoveClass` - это массив. Чтобы удалить класс, необходимо указать индекс элемента в этом массиве. Например, `imgRemoveClass[0].removeAttribute("class");` Либо же циклом.

Во втором случае, сложно сказать. Возможно скрипт загружается раньше, чем разметка. Также, может быть, что где-то буква `e`, `a` и тп. написана в кириллической раскладке  Попробуйте обратиться через `id`, например.

Comment: Вы меня направили очень грамотно. window.onload = function() {}

Answer (score 4):

Благодаря ответу [Дмытрык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/271553/%D0%94%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BA)
догодался о том что мой скрипт:

```
var imgRemoveClass = document.querySelector("img");
    if (imgRemoveClass.hasAttribute("class")) {
        imgRemoveClass.removeAttribute("class");
    }
```

тестируется в консоли уже на загруженной странице, тоесть DOM уже построен.
В случае добавления скрипта на страницу, скрипт выполняется раньше чем построен DOM, поэтому никаких атрибутов еще не существует и мы получаем ошибку.

**Решение:**

```
window.onload = function() {
var imgRemoveClass = document.querySelector("img");
        if (imgRemoveClass.hasAttribute("class")) {
            imgRemoveClass.removeAttribute("class");
        }
}
```

теперь скрипт исполняется только после полной загрузки документа и работает по назначению.